# What is the following variable?

Tags: javascript

When I run the command `x = 'test'.match(/(t(e)/)` in the console I get the following output.

`["te", "e", index: 0, input: "test"]`

I then run the following commands:

`x.length`
OUTPUT: `2`

`Object.keys(x).length`
OUTPUT: `4`

What is going on here? The variable seems to be an array literal with object literals at index 2 and 3. Sorry if this is a nooby question but when I try to do

`x = ["te", "e", index: 0, input: "test"]`
I get
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` which is expected, but im confused how the function is setting `x` to that.

Comment: The console is implementation dependent, what it shows it not necessarily a valid object or array literal. It's just trying to be helpful. See [*MDN String.prototype.match*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemme help a bit

- `["te", "e", index: 0, input: "test"]` is the stringified version of the object returned by the `match` function.
- `x` is not "set to that". `x` is set to an object describing the matches of your regex. When you do `console.log(x)`, `x.toString()` is called under the hood and returns `["te", "e", index: 0, input: "test"]`. That's just a text representation for convenience. The underlying structure is more complex.

Now for the other gotchas:

- `"te"` has been matched by your regex
- `"e"` is a capture from this match (because of the parentheses in your regexp)
- `x.length` describes the number of matches/captures found
- `Object.keys(x).length` is 4. You have 2 captures (2 keys), to which you add 2 keys for `index` and `input`

Comment: Not `x.toString`, but rather `proprietaryStringRepresentation(x)`

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are objects, the indexes are property names but not shown in array literals. The console is mixing array and object literal syntax (which is invalid if used as code).

An equivalent Object literal would be:

```
{
 0: "te",
 1: "e",
 index: 0,
 input: "test"
};
```

but object literals construct plain objects, not Array objects. You could construct an equivalent array using:

```
var x = ['te', 'e'];
x.index = 0;
x.input = 'test';
```

Answer (score 0):

The result of `'test'.match(/(t(e)/)` is really just `["te", "e"]`, which does have a length of 2, and seems to be what you want to get, so you can just use `x = ["te", "e"]`

Answer (score 0):

"Arrays are list-like objects whose prototype has methods to perform traversal and mutation operations." from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array]).

When you're accessing the 'index' or 'input' here, it's a property of an object, just like any other.

Try this:

```
a = new Array() 
a.hello = 'world' 
console.log(a.hello)
console.log(Object.keys(a))
```

You'll get the following output:

```
'world' 
['hello']
```